# Nodejs - Shortage of file size on nodejs archiver and fs stat

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

the logic of my program is as follow:

1. get object from aws s3
2. zip all the object obtained from s3 ( I create a zip file called a.zip )
3. put z.aip file to s3

Now I face a problem that my a.zip file always lack of a few bytes. From the following code snippet, the result of console.log(archive.pointer()) and console.log(stat.size) will be different. Does anyone have an idea ? Thank you.

```
async.map(filename, util.getS3Obj, function(err, result) {
   var archiver = require('archiver');
   var archive = archiver.create('zip', {});
   archive.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./tmp/Archive.zip'));
   for(var i=0 ; i<result.length ; i++) {
      archive.append(result[i], {name: fileNameArr[i]});
   }
   archive.finalize();

   archive.on('end', function() {
     console.log(archive.pointer());
     fs.stat('./tmp/Archive.zip', function(err, stat) {
        if(err) {}
        console.log(stat.size);    
      }); 
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by checking the file size in the close event of the createWriteStream without using end event of the archive. Because in the end event of archive, the writeFileStream is not finish.

```
var out = fs.createWriteStream('Archive.zip');
out.on('close', function() {
    // check file size here ...
});
```